# Strange activity on Apache httpd access log

Tags: apache, logging

I have set up an Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server on my Rasberry Pi. Looking at my access.log, I see a bit of strange activity consisting mostly of GETs, which is quite disconcerting as I am a complete newbie in such matters. The strangest thing was a series of POSTs consisting of percentage signs and numbers. I know next to nothing about web technologies, but I assumed they were escaped HTML characters. Decoding the characters of one of them (there were 2 varieties) from "POST php-cgi?" forwards, it resulted in the following:

> "POST /cgi-bin/php-cgi?-d+allow_url_include=on+-d+safe_mode=off+-d+suhosin.simulation=on-d+disable_functions=""+-d+open_basedir=none+-d+auto_ prepend_file=php://input+-d+ cgi.force_redirect=0+-d+cgi. redirect_status_env=0+-n"

And a sample GET:

> "GET /HNAP1/ HTTP/1.1"

What is going on here? Are bots randomly testing IP addresses for vulnerabilities? Should I be worried?

Edit: these requests returned 404.

Comment: @mods: i'm part of IT security for ~6 months now and i see the very same question occure every then and there, and i see the same answers every then and there; cant we just make a generic answer for this type of "oh, whats going on? my webserver-logs looks strange!!!!11!" - question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one looks like CGI injection.

Is your PHP updated? Are you sure it doesn't exist in the cgi-bin directory? These two should be enough to protect against this attack....

The second one appears to be targeting some D-Link vulnerabilities. I wouldn't worry about that one on your webserver.

Answer (score 0):

HNAP is the Home Network Administration Protocol.

There are exploits against D-Link routers that can be found using GET requests a bit like this.

You can find more info in this published exploit: http://www.sourcesec.com/Lab/dlink_hnap_captcha.pdf

Comment: Uh-oh, I have a D-Link router (GO-RT-N150).

Answer (score 0):

For more details about PHP-CGI vulnerability please refer :-

- cve-2012-1823 : http://cve.mitre.org/cgi-bin/cvename.cgi?name=CVE-2012-1823
- http://eindbazen.net/2012/05/php-cgi-advisory-cve-2012-1823/

Comment: This is essentially a link only answer.  Please include the pertinent details in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like [Zollard](http://www.symantec.com/connect/blogs/linux-worm-targeting-hidden-devices). It targets FastCGI deployments of PHP. If you run PHP, ensure that your webserver and PHP are up-to-date, and you should be fine.